# Unable to load the PKCS11_MODULE *.dll library using pkcs11

Tags: python, windows, dll, pkcs#11, hardware-security-module

I'm facing a problem when running the following script:

```
import pkcs11
import os
# Initialise our PKCS#11 library
lib = pkcs11.lib(os.environ['PKCS11_MODULE'])
```

The last line raises an error saying :
`ImportError: cannot import name '_pkcs11' from 'pkcs11' (C:\Users\xx\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pkcs11\__init__.py`

I tried to explicitly specify the path to the *.dll library :
`lib = pkcs11.lib("C:/path/to/LibFile.dll")`

But I keep getting the same error.

I am using the Utimaco HSM Simulator on Windows.

Has anyone seen the same error ?